# Visual Studio Express 2015 not using my include path

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, include-path

I have a library, libnoise to be specific, with header files installed under D:\src\include\noise\*.h

In my code which uses the library I have `#include <noise/noise.h>`

In the configuration properties for the project I have tried adding D:\src\include to both Include Directories and Additional Include Directories. When I check the generated command line it includes the flag `/I"D:\src\include"` as expected, however both Intellisense and the compiler itself report that they can't find the file.

I'm quite sure I'm missing something really stupid and obvious, but as you may have guessed I'm new to Microsoft compilers.

Comment: A shot in the dark, but could it be the direction of your slashes? / instead of \

Comment: Also make sure your changing the project settings for the correct configuration and platform.

Comment: No that's not it. However I've solved the issue by switching over to Community Edition. Still no idea why Express appears to ignore my include directories, but CE seems to be more well behaved so I'll use that going forward.